# Finding a vector given its dot products with given vectors

Tags: geometry

Given vectors $\vec{A} = -4.7\hat{\imath}  + 8.2\hat{\jmath}$  and $\vec{B}= 9.6\hat{\imath} + 6.7\hat{\jmath}$, determine the vector C that lies in the $xy$-plane perpendicular to $\vec{B}$ and whose dot product with $\vec{A}$ is $20.0$.

Can someone walk me through the steps of solving this problem? I need to solve for $\vec{C} = ?\hat{\imath} + ?\hat{\jmath}$

Comment: Hi, John: just a pointer. When you receive helpful answers, you can upvote them. You can also "accept" one answer per question, and you can do this by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "?", you can fill in the missing components with letters, say $x$ and $y$.  Suppose that $\vec C=x\hat i+y\hat j$.  Then $\vec C\cdot \vec A=-4.7 x+8.2y$.  What must the last expression equal? Similarly, write down an expression for $\vec C\cdot \vec B$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ to get an equation based on the assumptions in the problem.  Then try to solve the system of equations.

Comment: @Johnas Meyer, Would that mean that C*B = 9.6x + 6.7y ?

Comment: @John: Yes; and what should that be set equal to based on the assumption in the problem?

Comment: They should both be set to 20?

Comment: @John: No.  Only for $A$ does it say that the dot product is $20$.  What does it say about $B$, and how does that relate to the dot product?

Comment: To be quite honest I have no idea what that says for B.

Comment: @John: It says that $C$ is perpendicular to $B$, right?  Perhaps you have learned, or have a reference/book/notes, how perpendicularity is related to the dot product?  Do you have a geometric definition of the dot product involving angles, or at least know what the special case $\vec V\cdot \vec W=0$ signifies?

Comment: I am reading here that if A is perpendicular to be then A*Bcos(90)=0 by * I mean the dot product.

Comment: @John: Right, generally $\vec v\cdot \vec w=\|\vec v\|\|\vec w\|\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ (between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ or between $0$ and $\pi$ radians) is the angle between $\vec w$ and $\vec v$, and $\|\vec v\|$ means the length (or magnitude) of $\vec v$. The cosine of a right angle is $0$.  We don't need the full geometric definition, but here it is quite convenient to note that $\vec v\perp \vec w$ if and only if $\vec v\cdot \vec w=0$.

Comment: Alright but that leaves me with how I am supposed to solve this problem. I can't see how to solve for i and then j. Can you show me how it is done so I can make sense of it?

Comment: @John: You do not solve for $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. You should review what $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ mean.   From the above, you should get two equations with $x$ and $y$ in them.  There are several ways to solve this system of equations.  Here is a similar example.  Suppose $2x-3y =0$ and $1.5x+2y=4$.  Then from the first equation I can solve for $x$ to get $x=1.5y$.  I can substitute this in place of $x$ in the second equation to get $2.25y+2y=4$. Simplifying, $4.25y=4$.  Dividing by $4.25$ gives $y$, then I can substitute back to find $x$.

Comment: Do I solve this system of equations -4.7x + 8.2y = 20 and 6.7x -9.6 = 0?

Comment: @John: The first equation is correct, but the second isn't. Remember in your first comment, where you noted that $\vec C\cdot \vec B = 9.6x+6.7 y$; that is what should be set equal to $0$.

Comment: It should be the system $-4.7x + 8.2y = 20$ and $9.6x + 6.7y = 0$? :)

Comment: interesting i have solved for them and entered them into the computer and it still doesn't like my answers.

Comment: @John: Perhaps you can share your solution here; someone may chime in as to whether it is correct. Or you can check by entering the equations into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), for example.

Comment: Unfortunately I entered the system of equations into wolfram and the computer still doesn't like the answers.

Comment: @John: If you share your solution here, perhaps by editing it into your question, someone may let you know if there is a problem with it.

Comment: well using -4.7x + 8.2y = 20 and 6.7x + 9.6y = 0 gets x is roughly equal to -1.91885 and y is roughly 1.3392

Comment: @John: The second equation is incorrect; you have the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ switched.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $\vec C=c \hat i + d \hat j$, we need $\vec C \cdot \vec A= -4.7c+8.2d=20$ and $\vec C\cdot \vec B=0=9.6c+6.7d$.  This is two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I don't think you mean $\vec C\times \vec B$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
Vectors perpendicular to $\vec B = 9.6 i + 6.7j$ are of form $k (6.7 i - 9.6 j) $ for some scalar $k$.
Can you work out why and find $k$ from the condition on dot product with $\vec A$?